# Laravel custom error displaying

Tags: php, laravel, toastr

I previously used to include a `flash.blade.php` file within my blade templates that had rendered my errors from the session to the view using bootstrap alerts. Now I stumbled upon `laravel-5-toastr` which is really nice and exactly what I'm looking for. I just need to create a new `toastr` in my controller and redirect the user (or show them a view), and it works:

`Toastr::warning($message, $title);
return view('xy');`

Now I wonder how I can instruct Laravel to output errors using Toastr. I'm talking about validation errors and more stuff. For each and every error, there shall be displayed a seperate toastr. It both -doesn't work- and is considered bad practise to put the "toastr creation code" inside a view. Now, how can I achieve what I want? What I thought of is perhaps something like a middleware that checks whether the session has errors attached and if so, loops through the errors and creates toastrs. However, this doesn't -to me- seem like this was what middleware is for, so I thought of 'something' like that.

Looking forward to seeing suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually create validators. For example:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        foreach($validator->errors()->all() as $error) {
            Toastr::warning($error);
        }
        return back();
    }

    // Do whatever you need to when data is valid
}
```

You can visit Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#manually-creating-validators) on the subject.

Comment: This at least for the validation part does look interesting. THANKS!

Comment: @Johnny which other parts you want to use this? Can you be more specific!